# Group wise sum in Javascript object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Based on the inputArray i want to create outputArray, **marks** calculations in outputArray is like below

Group 1 = Physics + Chemistry + Maths

Group 2 = History + Geography

Group 3 = Language First + Language Second

Group Total = Group 1 + Group 2 + Group 3

```
var inputArray = [
  { subject: 'Physics', marks: '60' },
  { subject: 'History', marks: '35' },
  { subject: 'Chemistry', marks: '50' }, 
  { subject: 'Language First', marks: '70' },
  { subject: 'Geography', marks: '65' },
  { subject: 'Maths', marks: '40' },
  { subject: 'Language Second', marks: '50' },
  .
  .
  .
];

var outputArray = [
  { subject: 'Group 1', marks: '150' },
  { subject: 'Group 2', marks: '100' },
  { subject: 'Group 3', marks: '120' },
  { subject: 'Group Total', marks: '370' },
  .
  .
  .
];
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: And still no *question*…

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what's that `...` in each array..? How do they extend..?

Comment: 3 dot means same like other objects in array, there are more than 10 objects there but i have not mentioned all so i have used that dots.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using this code :

```
for(var i in inputArray){
   if(inputArray[i].subject == "Physics" || inputArray[i].subject == "Chemistry" || inputArray[i].subject == "Maths")
       outputArray[0].marks+= Number(inputArray[i].marks);

   else if(inputArray[i].subject == "History" || inputArray[i].subject == "Geography")
      outputArray[1].marks+= Number(inputArray[i].marks);

  else if(inputArray[i].subject == "Language Second" || inputArray[i].subject == "Language First")
      outputArray[2].marks+= Number(inputArray[i].marks);

}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjc4r3ma/1/)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This proposal works with some object, one as reference to subject's group, and another to the reference to the result set.

First, the result set is build, based on the wanted groups. In this loop, the reference generated.

Second, the `inputArray` is looped and the `marks` are added to the group where the subject is located. `marks` is added to *Group Total* as well.

```js
var inputArray = [{ subject: 'Physics', marks: '60' }, { subject: 'History', marks: '35' }, { subject: 'Chemistry', marks: '50' }, { subject: 'Language First', marks: '70' }, { subject: 'Geography', marks: '65' }, { subject: 'Maths', marks: '40' }, { subject: 'Language Second', marks: '50' }],
    groups = { 'Group 1': ['Physics', 'Chemistry', 'Maths'], 'Group 2': ['History', 'Geography'], 'Group 3': ['Language First', 'Language Second'], 'Group Total': null },
    reference = Object.create(null),
    subjects = Object.create(null),
    outputArray = Object.keys(groups).map(function (k) {
        reference[k] = { subject: k, marks: 0 };
        Array.isArray(groups[k]) && groups[k].forEach(function (a) { subjects[a] = k; });
        return reference[k];
    });

inputArray.forEach(function (a) {
    reference[subjects[a.subject]].marks += +a.marks;
    reference['Group Total'].marks += +a.marks
});

console.log(outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following solution using `Object.keys`, `Array.indexOf` functions and predefined `groupsMap` object:

```
var groupsMap = {
    'Group 1': ['Physics','Chemistry','Maths'],
    'Group 2': ['History','Geography'],
    'Group 3': ['Language First','Language Second']
}, output = {'Group Total': 0}, keys = Object.keys(groupsMap), len = keys.length;

inputArray.forEach(function(obj){
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (groupsMap[keys[i]].indexOf(obj['subject']) !== -1) {
            this[keys[i]] = this[keys[i]] || 0;
            this[keys[i]] += parseInt(obj['marks']);
            this['Group Total'] += parseInt(obj['marks']);
            break;  // avoids redundant iterations
        }
    }
}, output);

var outputArray = Object.keys(output).map((k) => ({'subject': k, 'marks': output[k]}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(outputArray, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "subject": "Group Total",
        "marks": 370
    },
    {
        "subject": "Group 1",
        "marks": 150
    },
    {
        "subject": "Group 2",
        "marks": 100
    },
    {
        "subject": "Group 3",
        "marks": 120
    }
]
```